# Regex for decimal with 1 to 9 digits before decima sign and 1 or 2 after decimal sign

Tags: regex, decimal

Looking for regex which will strictly allow 1 to 9 digits before  decimal dot(.) and 1 or 2 digits after dot(.)

**It should validate**

```
65564.54

654654654.45

1.55
```

**But not**

```
556

654654654

65455.6544

55.566
```

I have tried **`^[0-9]{1,9}\.[0-9]{1,2}$`**

Comment: The expressions looks good to me.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Doesn't it work?

Comment: Really ? I have tested it on my regex validator ? and seems like it is allowing 65455.6544 value. can u please check once..Thanks.

Comment: In JavaScript, `/^[0-9]{1,9}\.[0-9]{1,2}$/.test("65455.6544")` returns `false`. So yes, it works.

Comment: @JK: read it again..there is some difference.

Comment: Maybe you should check. Post a sample code snippet or a link to an on-line validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}$
```

http://rubular.com/r/IdYgiwNmoH

And for numbers not separated by linebreaks:

```
\b\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}\b
```

http://rubular.com/r/yVFJKsqsiZ

Answer (score 1):

The expression you've tried works fine, as long as you intend the number to be the entire line. If you're intending that the value be part of the line amongst other things, your `^` and `$` are the problems.

Comment: whats the problem with anchor tags?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine. I'm not sure what langauge you are working with, but you can verify javascript regex with Regex Pal:

http://regexpal.com/

Regular Expressions.info has a great built-in VB checker as well:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscriptexample.html